# android rabbitmq client connection out of memory

Tags: android, rabbitmq, out-of-memory

I have the following simple code that tries to connect to CloudAMQP using the RabbitMQ Java client to get messages. The logcat shows some connection being set up but then it throws an OutOfMemoryError (both on AVD and on physical device).
The OutOfMemory is thrown at the invocation of factory.newConnection() :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
try {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG, "MQuri: " + uri);
        factory.setUri(uri);
} catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.d("", "Connection broken: " + e1.getClass().getName() + ": " + e1.getMessage() );
        e1.printStackTrace();
}

factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.basicQos(1);

String MQQueue = MainActivity.getMQQueue(appcontext);
channel.queueDeclare(MQQueue, false, false, false, null);
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(MQQueue, false, consumer);
```

Any hint on what could be the cause?

Connection establishment is as follows:

```
07-22 05:22:24.533: I/dalvikvm-heap(833): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1345270078-byte allocation
07-22 05:22:24.603: D/dalvikvm(833): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 70K, 18% free 2588K/3140K, paused 59ms, total 60ms
07-22 05:22:24.603: E/dalvikvm-heap(833): Out of memory on a 1345270078-byte allocation.
07-22 05:22:24.603: I/dalvikvm(833): "AMQP Connection 146.148.11.249:443" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
07-22 05:22:24.603: I/dalvikvm(833):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x416f23a0 self=0x2a1be3e8
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   | sysTid=853 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=706471992
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   | state=R schedstat=( 99662493 40632307 23 ) utm=8 stm=1 core=0
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:~116)
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:542)
07-22 05:22:24.634: I/dalvikvm(833):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-22 05:22:24.673: D/(833): Connection broken: java.io.IOException: null
07-22 05:22:24.683: W/System.err(833): java.io.IOException
```

Comment: Your trying to allocate 1+GB of memory and don't have enough free, or there you should increase JVM limit...

Comment: I'm not trying to allocate memory. The RabbitMQ java client is used; that must have trying to allocate too much memory for an unknown reason: the `newConnection()` function. I've seen many examples using  RabbitMQ java client, but none of them was facing this problem. Changing the heap size might be a workaround, but Android devices won't have that much heap available.

Comment: Changing the port number from 443 (SSL) to AMQP's default one solved the issue.